# How to namespace Destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two sets of data `valOne` and `valTwo` and has same keys `expense` and `allocated`:

```
// data
const valOne = { expense: 1000, allocated: 2000 };
let valTwo = { expense: 0, allocated: 0 };

// Destructuring assignment
const { expense, allocated } = valOne;
let { expense, allocated } = valTwo;
```

Certainly I cannot do this, right? So, how to make it work :)

```
expense = expense;
allocated = allocated;
```

as of now I am seeing just one way of doing it is:

```
// data
const valOne = { expense: 1000, allocated: 2000 };
let valTwo = { expense: 0, allocated: 0 };

const { expense, allocated } = valOne;

valTwo.expense = expense;
valTwo.allocated = allocated;
```

So, my question is:

```
// how to namespace these?
         |          |
let { expense, allocated } = valTwo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your own identifiers as value as done in below example:

You can find details of destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
// data
const valOne = { expense: 1000, allocated: 2000 };
let valTwo = { expense: 0, allocated: 0 };

const { expense: exp, allocated: allo } = valOne;

console.log(exp, allo);
```